# GPS failed to be off inside onPause() of a FragmentActivity

Tags: android, gps

I have a FragmentActivity hosting a MapActivity and ListActivity. Each activity calls a LocationManager method to obtain the user's current location. I'm trying to make the GPS off when the app runs on the background.

When I tried to run each Activity separately, I don't have any problem at all. The method inside onPause works. The GPS logo didin't appear anymore on the phone's Notification Bar.
But when I run the FragmentActivity which hosts both the Map and ListActivity, when I hit the back button, the GPS logo is still there.

I don't know why it happened, can somebody tell me what are the possibilities maybe?

FYI: I don't call any locationManager method inside my FragmentActivity.

Here are my onPause() and onResume() methods on both activities:

```
@Override
    public void onResume() {        

        if (locationListener != null)
        {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);            
        locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 1000, 10f, locationListener);
        }
        super.onResume();
    }


    @Override
    public void onPause() {             
        locationManager.removeUpdates(locationListener);
        locationManager = null;
        super.onPause();
    }
```

**UPDATE: I FOUND THE PROBLEM**
Here's my FragmentActivity

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle bundle) {

        WWHApplication.setFragmentInstance(this);
        WWHApplication.getInstance().getJsonDBInstance();
        Util.isJsonDBDownloaded();

        super.onCreate(bundle);
        setContentView(R.layout.main_fragment_activity_alt);

        cbAll = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.cb_tab_all);
        cbAll.setChecked(true);
        cbAll.setOnClickListener(this);

        cbFavorites = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.cb_tab_favorites);
        cbFavorites.setOnClickListener(this);

        cbHistorical = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.cb_tab_historical);
        cbHistorical.setOnClickListener(this);

        cbFood = (RadioButton) findViewById(R.id.cb_tab_food);
        cbFood.setOnClickListener(this);

        slidingDrawer = (MultiDirectionSlidingDrawer) findViewById(R.id.drawer);


        //Always prepare content on start
        WWHApplication.setCategory('a');
        WWHApplication.getListActivityIntance().loadListView();
        animate();

        animateStart();

    }

    public void animateStart() {
        slidingDrawer.animateOpen();
    }


    public void animate() {
        slidingDrawer.refreshContent();
    }


    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        switch (v.getId()) {
        case R.id.cb_tab_all:
            WWHApplication.setCategory('a');
            WWHApplication.getListActivityIntance().loadListView();
            animate();

            break;
        case R.id.cb_tab_favorites:
            WWHApplication.setCategory('f');
            WWHApplication.getListActivityIntance().loadListView();
            animate();

            break;
        case R.id.cb_tab_historical:

            break;
        case R.id.cb_tab_food:

            break;
        }

    }
```

When I comment out the all  the following lines inside of the Activity, the GPS off method inside onPause() is working:

```
WWHApplication.setCategory('a');
WWHApplication.getListActivityIntance().loadListView();
```

the problem is I need to call both lines, anybody have a solution that I'm stil able to call those methods above while the GPS off method inside the onPause() is still working?

Comment: is your MapActivity and ListActivity extends Fragment or Activity?

Comment: Weird, the same code is working for me, even with the support library (with the mapview refactoring). It may be something related to your backstack management. Are these methods properly called ?

Comment: I've just updated my question. Pls have a look, found the problem, yet still looking for the solution. Thx